# App is still showing in debuggable after making debuggable false in app graddle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, build-variant

I have two build variants uat and prod.
In uat I am making `debuggable` to true while in prod I am making it to `false`.
But app is still showing in `debuggable` after making it to `false`.
It's happen only in case of emulator.

following is code in my app graddle file

```
buildTypes {
        android.variantFilter { variant ->
            if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release') || variant.buildType.name.equals('debug')) {
                variant.setIgnore(true);
            }
        }
        uat {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.uat
            minifyEnabled false

            //zipAlignEnabled true
            applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
            buildConfigField "String", "URL_ENDPOINT", "\"http://your.development.endpoint.com/\""

        }

        prod {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prod
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
           // zipAlignEnabled true
            applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note : you will want to be able to debug prod builds.

Comment: @SombreroChicken no, I don't wanted to do debug in prod but app is showing in debuggable process though I make it to false.